# Full traffic redirect

Tags: linux, networking, redirect

I've the following network layout:
[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LaXRh.jpg)

I need to permit to [PC 1] to comunicate with [NETWORK DEVICE] placed in the other side of wan.
The software in [PC 1] must "see" [NETWORK DEVICE] in local area network, so can connect only to 192.168.0.x devices.
The 2 linux gateways have slackware 14 so.

How can i solve?

Thank you very much.
Alberto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On gateway 192.168.0.1, you need to add another IP address that will represent the device 192.168.1.7 - assume it will be 192.168.0.107.

Also on the same gateway you must add NAT rules in `iptables` that will perform a destination NAT from 192.168.0.107 to 192.168.1.7 in PREROUTING chain, and a source NAT from 192.168.1.7 to 192.168.0.107 in POSTROUTING chain. Something like:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s 192.168.0.8/32 -d 192.168.0.107/32 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.7
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.7/32 -d 192.168.0.8/32 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.0.107
```